# Yii2: 404 error trying to go to multiple words model's index

Tags: model, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I try to go to a an index for a model named "ServicioPeluquero", but it has 2 words, so when I try to go its index, it couldn't show. I tried this urls:

```
localhost/yii2basic/web/index.php?r=serviciopeluquero
localhost/yii2basic/web/index.php?r=servicioPeluquero
localhost/yii2basic/web/index.php?r=servicio_peluquero
```

I will thank if can help with that, please.

Comment: try localhost/yii2basic/web/index.php?r=servicio%20peluquero

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how your model is named, what matters is your controller name. You should use hyphen as word separator of camel-cased controllers. So assuming that your controller name is `ServicioPeluqueroController`, you should use:

```
localhost/yii2basic/web/index.php?r=servicio-peluquero
```

Comment: Trying that got me a View Not Found Exception.

Comment: Thats a different problem - it's hard to guess without knowing your action content and views structure. But I guess you should have a view file in `views/servicio-peluquero/index.php` and it is missing in your case. And that error actually means that controller and its action was found, so URL is correct. I suggest to start from reading guide about controllers and views: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-views